# MySQL - Why my table does not exists with the foreign keys check, then does exists when doing a SELECT and disabling the check?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a MySQL database with innoDB engine.

Today, the website had an issue and could not display, because a table does not exists. In phpMyAdmin, the table definitively exists as you can see in the left panel, unless the red warning at the top.

[image: Text]

When I tried a simple SELECT in the table, with the foreign keys check, same issue, as you can see.

[image: Text]

After that, I tried to **disable** the foreign keys check, and I could read my data. And the website worked well.

But then, I tried the same SELECT, **with** the foreign keys check, and it worked. It seems the issue was solved, but I don't know what went wrong.

It's not the first time I have this issue, and I'm affraid it's not the last. I need to find what's wrong, what to do to avoid a future issue. Any idea of what to do to prevent, or what to do to find the source issue? Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if the missing table is the tabled referenced in the FK. Also if you query the information_schema do they show your table exists?

Comment: The table is referenced in the FK of some table, and it also contains FK. Yes it shows the table exists. But I don't know if it would have been the same during the issue...